# Objects in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently redesigning a site using svg. However I have run into several issues that I have yet to solve. This is a three part question.

1. How do you make an object which is an svg file dynamically change to fit on screen that are smaller than the viewbox without  the file getting cropped. The svg file in this case is diagonal arrow.
2. How do you keep text in the same location based on this dynamically changing image, so that the arrow always points to the text no matter the screen size, without using vague @media queries throughout the css file (eg. min-width:15 to max-width:40...). [Example of the arrow with the apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmBD7.png)
3. When using objects in html, how do I replace an object with another object based on screen size. For example I have an svg of an apple above the arrow and when the screen resolution hits 1000px it shows this arrow and when its below it shows a flipped version of this arrow. It would have been easy using srcset with img, but because I have the to change color of the arrows using svg styling I can't use img.

Thank you for all your help.
[Dropbox file of website](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aruyce49685ffiq/AACWvlwuMpMMfI_FsDHLtqtPa?dl=0)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Comatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://orgrune.com/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="clearview col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-uppercase">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <hr class="hr-cl">
    </header>
    <div class="clearview col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="svg-container">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://orgrune.com/Untitled-3.svg" class="svg-content "></object>
      </div>
      </svg>
      <a class="photography text-uppercase" href="\" alt="photography">photography</a>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. use a viewBox 2. add your code so far to the question itself (not a screenshot) 3. see 2

Comment: I have attached an example code. You will need to change the link files on your computer to get the css to work.

Comment: I have attached the code to the question itself as you have requested.